# Send Events to Event Grid Topic from ADF Web activity with MSI authentication

Tags: azure-data-factory, rbac, azure-eventgrid, azure-managed-identity

I wish to send an event from ADF "Web" Activity to event grid topic. I managed to do it with sending "aeg-sas-key" from web activity as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/custom-event-quickstart-portal).
However, I tried to achieve the same through ADF Web activity without using "aeg-sas-key" but Authentication as managed identity

[image]

But it gives me below error:

> { "error": { "code": "Unauthorized", "message": "Request has an
> unsupported Authorization scheme:Bearer. Authorization scheme must be
> SharedAccessSignature. Report
> 'a2af905c-e3ca-401a-be09-3f0b3c6b7d4e:8:5/20/2021 2:00:24 PM (UTC)' to
> our forums for assistance or raise a support ticket."

I have added the managed Identity Application of ADF to Event Grid topic with contributor role, but it still does not work. Am I missing something?

[image]

To be short, I need to know how to send events to Event Grid topic from ADF Web Activity **using Managed Identity Authentication**?

Comment: According to the error, we cannot use azure ad auth to send events to azure event grid topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all the APIs in Azure support MSI auth, just the APIs secured by Azure AD support that, essentially the MSI auth uses the [Azure AD client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) to get the token, then use the token to call the API.

In this case, as mentioned in the error message,  to [send an event to your topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/custom-event-quickstart-portal#send-an-event-to-your-topic), it uses `aeg-sas-key` to auth, i.e. Basic auth, it does not support the Azure AD auth which means it also could not use MSI to auth.

Comment: Thanks @joy Wang. Seems we have to use sas only until this feature is available.